# Operação entre modelos

Tags: javascript

Não conheço muito bem o poder do javascript, mas queria fazer o seguinte:

Tenho dois modelos:

Vaga:

```
{
    Name: "VagaExemplo",
    Description: "Descricao",
    Skills: {
        "56b68108869038280db291e6": "90",
        "56b68108869038280db291d9": "70",
    }
}
```

e vários modelos do tipo:

Pessoa1

```
{
    Name: "PessoaExemplo",
    Description: "Descricao",
    Skills: {
        "56b68108869038280db291d9": "60",
    },
    Pontuacao: 10
}
```

Pessoa2

```
{
    Name: "PessoaExemplo2",
    Description: "Descricao",
    Skills: {
        "56b68108869038280db291e6": "90",
        "56b68108869038280db291d9": "80",
    },
    Pontuacao: 0
}
```

A ideia é multiplicar o valor de cada skill da vaga com a da pessoa e ir somando, para gerar uma pontuação para cara pessoa.

Alguém poderia me ajudar ou pelo menos um link com um material a respeito? Abraços.

Comment: _"multiplicar o valor de cada skill da vaga com a da pessoa "_ ou multiplicar com a pontuação? como assim "com a pessoa"?

Comment: por exemplo, a pessoa também possui uma skill (são identificadas pelos ids), penso em algo tipo, Pessoa1.Pontuacao =  60 x 70 ( que é 4200) 
Pessoa2.Pontuacao = (90 X 90) + (80 x 70)  (que é 13700).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que o que procuras é isto:

```
var pontos = pessoas.map(function(pessoa) {
    var pontos = 0;
    Object.keys(pessoa.Skills).forEach(function(codigo) {
        pontos += parseInt(tabela.Skills[codigo], 10) * parseInt(pessoa.Skills[codigo], 10);
    });
    return pontos;
});
```

Partindo do principio que cada pessoa é um objeto, dentro de uma array.

#### Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/pvfpawn1/

Se quiseres ter também o nome da pessoa no resultado final podes fazer assim: https://jsfiddle.net/pvfpawn1/1/

---

O que este código faz é saber quantas `Skills` a pessoa tem com `Object.keys(pessoa.Skills)`. Depois para cada código dessa skill vai à tabela buscar o multiplicador. Uso `parseInt` pois esses numeros estão como *String*, se fossem numeros não seria preciso.

Comment: cara, era exatamente isso que precisava. Muito obrigado mesmo. Grande abraço.